# align li tags with an auto width vs hard coding

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble trying to get a group of li tags to align how I want.

I have some basic html

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
</div>​
```

and some css

```
.menu
{
 border:solid 2px red;
 width:520px;
}

ul
{
border:solid 1px #e5e5e5;
height:40px;
margin:0 auto;
list-style:none;
width:500px;
}

li{

text-align:center;
display:inline;
margin:10px;

}
```

I dont want to hard code li widths for each of the elements but I would like for the li elements to take up all available space with the ul element.

What do I need to change to get the result I am looking for?

[My attempt on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spnz/XmcGh/)

Comment: I know it's a cliche, but here's a one-liner with jquery: `​$('li').css('width', $('ul').width() / $('li').length​​​​​​​​​​​);​`

Comment: i m not aderstand of you question ?

Comment: what do mean by ` the li elements to take up all available space with the ul element.`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if i understand your question may be have to use display:table property for this. Write like this:

```
ul
{
    border:solid 1px #e5e5e5;
    height:40px;
    margin:0 auto;
    list-style:none;
    width:500px;
    display:table;
}

li{
 display:table-cell;
 text-align:center;    
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/XmcGh/2/

Comment: Beat me to it! But I would add the caveat that support for this kind of styling is robust but not perfect, so Dan should test in all his target browsers. But what *is* well-supported is... tables! I don't know when we all got allergic to tables, but if it should act like a table, why not use a table? But anyhow, the above is still the first answer I would give, too.

Comment: IE7 isn't supported, but everything else that people use will be. IE7 use is down to a couple percentage points most places except China. I say drop support!

Answer (score 0):

If `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` doesn't cut it, you could use percentage widths and floating.  Though that kind of goes against your "no hard code li widths" requirement.  Though percentages would flex with various view-port sizes.

This would also only work if the number of `<li>` was constant.

Something like:

```
<ul>
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
<li>four</li>
</ul>

ul {
width: 100%;
}
li {
float: left;
text-align: center;
width: 30%;
}
```